# Is there a way to delay a popstate event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pushstate, popstate

I've tried a few methods to see if I can create a cross browser solution for delaying a popstate event but have not had any luck.

Anyone have any ideas or thoughts?

Below obviously does not work, but something to the effect of:

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(e) {

   // something here to delay the history pageload        

      console.log('a wild console has appeared!');

});
```

So the flow would follow this sequence:

- Browser "back" or "forward" button clicked
- run initial code
- A delay before the page changes
- page change

Comment: And why wouldn't that work, assuming the popstate event was fired by changing the history, and not a real pageload

Comment: It should work - are you including jquery in your page (before you use your code)?

Comment: sorry the console part of it was probably confusing - to clarify, what I am looking for is a way to delay the actual loading of the next page when popstate is triggered. I'll update the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate) the popstate event is

> only triggered by doing a browser action such as a click on the back button

So I do not believe it will get triggered when user clicks 'forward' (and it varies in some browsers)

For reference, here's the full text:

> The popstate event is fired when the active history entry changes. If the history entry being activated was created by a call to history.pushState() or was affected by a call to history.replaceState(), the popstate event's state property contains a copy of the history entry's state object.
>
> Note that just calling history.pushState() or history.replaceState() won't trigger a popstate event. **The popstate event is only triggered by doing a browser action such as a click on the back button** (or calling history.back() in JavaScript).
>
> Browsers tend to handle the popstate event differently on page load. Chrome (prior to v34) and Safari always emit a popstate event on page load, but Firefox doesn't.

**UPDATED ANSWER ABOVE**

<del>Your code works.  (see below) - I added an element to trigger the event (you can see the results in the console)</del>

Make sure you include the jQuery library on your HTML prior to using it though.

```js
$(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
  console.log('fired instantly!');
  var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('delayed popstate!');
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }, 1000);
});

$(window).trigger( 'popstate') ;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the example - I updated my example for clarity, any thoughts?

Comment: "The popstate event is fired when the active history entry changes." - this is what I am looking to delay -- before the page change